# Can't open the wearable-preview-support.jar for Android Wear

Tags: wear-os

I'm trying to run the wearable-preview-support.jar from terminal and I get the error
java -jar wearable-preview-support.jar 
Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from
wearable-preview-support.jar

Also just trying to open the jar by double clicking gives the error: 
The Java JAR file "wearable-preview-support.jar" could not be launched. Check the Console for possible error messages.﻿

No error messages were displayed in Console.

Anyone else having this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The JAR isn't a self contained executable, it is a library to build the wearable apps off of. See [this page](https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/start.html) for more information about how to use it. You have to reference it as a library in your Android application in order to run it, and you will have to run it in the Android virtual machine.

[Here are some steps](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/03/18/taking-the-android-wear-preview-sdk-for-a-spin-notifications-notifications-and-more-notifications-detailed-hands-on-with-gifs-galore/) to get Android Wear working in a virtual machine. Keep in mind it might be a little underwhelming using it with a mouse since it'll be less responsive than the actual device will be (hopefully).

Comment: I don't understand, I am following that page and I'm at this part:
After you install the Android Wear Preview app, you can set up your device to communicate with the Android Wear emulator:

Open the Android Wear Preview app. You should see a notice that the app is currently not enabled as a notification listener. Tap the message to open the system settings, then select Android Wear Preview to grant it notification access.

What does it mean "Open the Android Wear Preview app"?

Comment: That is a step for after you have setup the Android Wear Emulator. If you haven't done that yet, then do the steps in order. When they say "Open the Android Wear Preview app", then mean open it in the emulated environment. The preview app is an app for developers to look at as a reference for how to use Android Wear.

Answer (score 1):

The jar file should be included in your Android application, you do not run it directly.

The "Android Wear Preview app" is an application you download from the Google Play Store which runs on your real device. You can only download this application if google have enabled you do. For this to happen you need to sign up at the [Google wear preview signup](http://developer.android.com/wear/preview/start.html) - once you have downloaded the application, you then grant it notification access.